# DataGrid binding with sql server database

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I am simply binding a database table with datagrid. I am getting this excption 
"Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation." I have google it but didn't able to find the reason. what I am doing wrong? Or is this due to some other factor?

here is my code.
In XAML

```
 <DataGrid Name="data_grid"  AutoGenerateColumns="True"/>
```

In .cs

```
SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(getString());
        cn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from data", cn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter adpp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        adpp.Fill(ds);
        data_grid.DataContext = ds;
        cn.Close();
```

Instead of dataset I have also try by using datatable.

```
datatable dt = new datatable;
adpp.Fill(dt);
data_grid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
```

I have debug it. I got exception on function where I getting connectionstring from app1.config.

```
public string getString() {
           return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconnection"].ConnectionString.ToString();

     }
```

and the app1.config code is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="myconnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=daniwpf;Integrated Security=True"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: When does the exception occur?  Could you provide a stacktrace?

Comment: We need more information. When you get the error dialog popping up, click on the 'View details' link to find out more. Please let us know what details you find out. Also, look in the 'Output' window in Visual Studio to see if there are any errors there.

Comment: when I run the project I got this exception.

Comment: see the inner exception it will tell you what is wrong

Comment: In inner exception I got this detail {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}. But Not finding any such object.

Comment: Please debug your application step by step using (F10),you will surely found it

Answer (score 0):

You need correct in your code - `adpp.Fill(ds,"MyDataBinding");`

and in *MainWindow.xaml* - `DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyDataBinding}"`